# Cannot get checkins via FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could you tell me why I can't get checkins by calling `/me/checkins` ? In Graph API Explorer I specified permissions `user_status` and `friends_status` for my app. I get following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#602) page_id is not a member of the checkin table.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 602
  }
}
```

Interestingly enough if I switch app to "Graph API Explorer" and give it same permissions it works.

Am I missing something in settings of my app ?

*Update*: And here is debug info of my token (taken from **[here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)**)

```
Info

App ID: 587071704636494 : Something
User ID: 100005276526713 : Something
Issued: Unknown 
Expires: 1365148800 (this Friday)  
Valid: True 
Origin: Unknown 
Scopes: friends_status read_stream user_status
```

Comment: please post the code of how you are calling the API

Comment: @Mupps I just use Graph Explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 1):

I think it was the beginning of these changes:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

> FQL Checkin table 'page_id' change: We are renaming 'page_id' to
>   'target_id' for the Checkin table.

Again, thanks Zuckerberg!